# Need to Convert this SQL query to LINQ

Tags: linq, t-sql

can anybody help me to convert this SQL query to LINQ code in MVC? I need to return a list. The DB context entity is: _dbContext.

```
select distinct table1.AIG_ID, table1.GMT_NAME, table1.AIG_Number
from table1 left join table2 on table1.AIG_ID = table2.AIG_ID**
```

Comment: whats the reason for the Left Join?  take it away and you might not need Distinct and you can just use `var t = _dbContext.table1.ToList();`

Comment: thanks for your quick response, this is the original codes. I think there is a relationship between table1 and table2 which need left join with the condition of table1.AIG_ID = table2.AIG_ID.

Comment: The original codes like this: select distinct table1.AIG_ID, coalesce([table1].[GMT_NAME], 'AIG' + cast([table1].[AIG_Number] as varchar(20))) as AIG_Name
  from table1 left join table2 on table1.AIG_ID = table2.AIG_ID

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var data=(from item in db.table1 join
item1 in db.table2 on item.AIG_ID equals item1.AIG_ID 
select new {item.AIG_ID ,item.GMT_NAME ,item.AIG_Number }).GroupBy(a=>a.AIG_ID).select(a=>a.FirstOrDefault()).ToList();
```

I write this part for your distinct in sql

```
GroupBy(a=>a.AIG_ID).select(a=>a.FirstOrDefault())
```